# Is an irreducible representation always isomorphic with a subgroup?

Tags: group-theory

I apologize if that's a terribly obvious question. I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of the basics of group theory, I think the answer is "Yes" but want to check my work, so to speak.

And: If "yes", is it also the case that every subgroup is isomorphic with an irreducible representation?

Comment: Consider S3. One of its subgroups is A3. The standard representation of A3 (1, exp(2/3 pi i), exp(4/3 pi i)) is also an irreducible representation of S3. I'm wondering if this is always the case.

Comment: A representation is a homomorphism so the question does not make much sense. Are you asking whether the image of an irreducible representation of a group $G$ is always isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$? The answer to that is certainly no. For example ${\rm SL}(n,q)$ has irreducible representations with image isomorphic to ${\rm PSL}(n,q)$.

Comment: "Are you asking whether the image of an irreducible representation of a group G is always isomorphic to a subgroup of G?"  Yes, that's what I was asking, and I see that the answer is No. Gad, this book I'm working from is *dreadful*...

Answer (score 1):

For example, let $G = \mathbb R$ (with addition), and consider the irreducible representation $\pi: \mathbb R \to \text{Aut}(\mathbb R^2)$ where $\pi(t) = \pmatrix{\cos(t) & \sin(t)\cr -\sin(t) & \cos(t)\cr} $.  $\pi(\mathbb R)$ contains periodic elements, but $\mathbb R$ has none, so $\pi(\mathbb R)$ is not isomorphic to any subgroup of $\mathbb R$.